# PHP Grammar in Xtext

Tags: php, xhtml, xtext

I am researching processes of modernization and Web Reigieneria and I need to define grammars for PHP and XHTML to generate code XText after defining metamodels.

Has someone made some progress which I can base to?

Comment: What is Web Reigieneria?

Comment: Sorry, I meant reverse engineering of web applications and then create new web applications while maintaining the same conditions but improving some aspects. All with automatic processes such as MDA

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find an Ecore model of XHTML : http://www.emn.fr/z-info/atlanmod/index.php/Ecore#XHTML_1.0
And here you can find some pointers to get XText working with existing ecore metamodels : http://5ise.quanxinquanyi.de/2011/02/16/xtext-and-existing-ecore-making-use-of-the-atlan-model-zoo/

Regards